# round the two ends of thick line with xml shape

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-shape

I have a line shape, it is a thick line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="30">
    <shape android:shape="line">
        <size
            android:width="100dp"
            android:height="100dp" />
        <stroke
            android:width="30dp"
            android:color="#0000FF" />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

I am wondering is there any way to make the line's two ends **rounded**?

I tried adding this to above `<shape>`:

```
<corners android:radius="10dp"/>
```

But it doesn't take any effect for thick line.

Comment: Use `android:shape="rectangle"` instead, then you can add the corner radius.

Comment: How to make rectangle looks like a line?

Comment: Make one dimension larger than the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `View tag` in your `xml` something like this which represents the line. Adjust the height for varying thickness of the line.

```
<View
   android:layout_width="100dp"
   android:layout_height="10dp"
   android:background="@drawable/test"/>
```

And then add the usual *background* for it like you've done

*test.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#000000" />
<corners android:radius="8dip" />
</shape>
```

This first gave me *no start tag* found error but on *clean and rebuild* it produced the required output. Try it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please try my code, I changed to rectangle, and height 1 dp, my line disappears.

Comment: Sorry I'm afk, just try giving a background color and see if you can see the line. If you don't I'll try and update the solution.

Comment: no...can't see, & one more problem, if I have a short line with current height, it looks like a diamond than a line.

Comment: Okay then adding a View element in xml with height and width 1dp will you give you a proper line short or long and then,add your code above with the radius as the view's background. I'll update the code in 5 mins, adjust view's width to make it thick